# Having trouble with my views and formsets saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am having the hardest time with my views and formsets saving. I have come to realize that views are my weakness in Django. I have been working on this for the past few months and writing and rewriting the code. I know this is the best way to learn. Luckily my team gave me this project to learn from. But I still don't know where I am going wrong.

If anyone here sees where I am off or pointing me into the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm searching for best resources to get stronger in this area.

Here is my Views:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from itertools import chain

from .models import *
from .forms import *
from .emailtemplates import OrderFormNotification


class OrderFormProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self, contact=None, contact_form_class=ContactForm,
        letterhead_form_class=LetterHeadFormSet,
        windowenv_form_class=WindowEnvFormSet,
        numbertenenv_form_class=NumberTenEnvFormSet,
        ninebytwelveenv_form_class=NineByTwelveEnvFormSet,
        tenbythirteenenv_form_class=TenByThirteenEnvFormSet,
        businesscard_form_class=BusinessCardFormSet,
        send_notification=False):
    self.contact_form_class = contact_form_class
    self.letterhead_form_class = letterhead_form_class
    self.windowenv_form_class = windowenv_form_class
    self.numbertenenv_form_class = numbertenenv_form_class
    self.ninebytwelveenv_form_class = ninebytwelveenv_form_class
    self.tenbythirteenenv_form_class = tenbythirteenenv_form_class
    self.businesscard_form_class = businesscard_form_class
    self.send_notification = send_notification
    self.contact = contact

def process(self, request, context=None):
    if not context:
        context = {}

    contact = self.contact

    data = request.POST or None

    contact_form = self.contact_form_class(data,
            instance=contact)

    forms = dict(
        contact_form=contact_form,
    )

    formsets = dict(
        letterhead_formset=self.letterhead_form_class(data,                 prefix='letterhead_'),
        windowenv_formset=self.windowenv_form_class(data, prefix='windowenv_'),
        numbertenenv_formset=self.numbertenenv_form_class(data, prefix='numbertenenv_'),
        ninebytwelveenv_formset=self.ninebytwelveenv_form_class(data, prefix='ninebytwelveenv_'),
        tenbythirteenenv_formset=self.tenbythirteenenv_form_class(data, prefix='tenbythirteenenv_'),
        businesscard_formset=self.businesscard_form_class(data, prefix='businesscard_'),
    )

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_is_valid = all([f.is_valid() for f in forms.values() + \
                formsets.values()])
        if form_is_valid:
            contact = forms['contact_form'].save(commit=False)

            contact.letterhead_form = formsets['letterhead_formset'].save()
            contact.windowenv_form = formsets['windowenv_formset'].save()
            contact.numbertenenv_form = formsets['numbertenenv_formset'].save()
            contact.ninebytwelveenv_form = formsets['ninebytwelveenv_formset'].save()
            contact.tenbythirteenenv_form = formsets['tenbythirteenenv_formset'].save()
            contact.businesscard_form = formsets['businesscard_formset'].save()

            contact.save()

            if self.send_notification:
                email = OrderFormNotification(to=[settings.NO_REPLY_EMAIL_ADDRESS],
                extra_context=data)
                email.send()
        else:
            pass

    all_forms = chain(forms.values(), chain.from_iterable(formsets.values()))
    context = context.copy()
    context.update(forms.items() + formsets.items())
    context.update(
        error_list=list(chain.from_iterable([form.errors.values() for form in all_forms])),
    )

    return (forms, formsets), context


class OrderFormView(View):
    template_name = 'orderform.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        processor = OrderFormProcessor(send_notification=True)

        (forms, formsets), context = processor.process(request)
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)


class ThankYou(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'thank-you.html'
```

Here are my Forms:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm, extras
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
from django.contrib.localflavor import us

from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect, CheckboxSelectMultiple

from .models import *


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES,)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact


class LetterHeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = LetterHead
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'quantity': forms.Select(choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES),
        }


class WindowEnvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = WindowEnv
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'quantity': forms.Select(choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES),
        }


class NumberTenEnvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = NumberTenEnv
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'quantity': forms.Select(choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES),
        }


class NineByTwelveEnvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = NineByTwelveEnv
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'quantity': forms.Select(choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES),
        }


class TenByThirteenEnvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    address = forms.ChoiceField(required = False, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = TenByThirteenEnv
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'quantity': forms.Select(choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES),
        }


class BusinessCardForm(forms.ModelForm):
    print_choices = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=PRINT_CHOICES)
    card_styles = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=CARD_CHOICES)
    card_mailing_address = forms.ChoiceField(required = True, widget=RadioSelect(), choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessCard
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
        }


class RushOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RushOrder
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'rush_order': forms.CheckboxInput,
            'in_hand_date': forms.extras.SelectDateWidget
        }


class OrderNoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OrderNote
        widgets = {
            'contact': forms.HiddenInput,
            'add_note': forms.CheckboxInput,
            'notes': forms.Textarea
        }


LetterHeadFormSet = modelformset_factory(LetterHead,
    form=LetterHeadForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
WindowEnvFormSet = modelformset_factory(WindowEnv,
    form=WindowEnvForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
NumberTenEnvFormSet = modelformset_factory(NumberTenEnv,
    form=NumberTenEnvForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
NineByTwelveEnvFormSet = modelformset_factory(NineByTwelveEnv,
    form=NineByTwelveEnvForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
TenByThirteenEnvFormSet = modelformset_factory(TenByThirteenEnv,
    form=TenByThirteenEnvForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
BusinessCardFormSet = modelformset_factory(BusinessCard,
    form=BusinessCardForm, extra=2, max_num=2)
```

Here are the Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import PhoneNumberField

PRINT_CHOICES = (
    ('exact reprint', 'Exact Reprint'),
    ('reprint with changes', 'Reprint With Changes'),
    ('new', 'New')
)

QUANTITY_CHOICES = (
    ('1000', '1000'),
    ('2500', '2500'),
    ('5000', '5000')
)

CARD_QUANTITY_CHOICES = (
    ('250', '250'),
    ('500', '500'),
    ('1000', '1000')
)

CARD_CHOICES = (
    ('chef/black', 'Chef/Black'),
    ('executive/red', 'Executive/Red')
)

ADDRESS_CHOICES = (
    ('eisenhower', 'Eisenhower'),
    ('wheeler', 'Wheeler'),
)


class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="First Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Last Name")
    email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=275)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class BaseStationary(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='%(class)s_related')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=QUANTITY_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class LetterHead(BaseStationary):
    pass


class WindowEnv(BaseStationary):
    pass


class NumberTenEnv(BaseStationary):
    pass


class NineByTwelveEnv(BaseStationary):
    pass


class TenByThirteenEnv(BaseStationary):
    pass


class BusinessCard(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='businesscards')
    card_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    card_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    print_choices = models.CharField(max_length=19, choices=PRINT_CHOICES)
    card_styles = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=CARD_CHOICES)
    card_email_address = models.EmailField(max_length=275)
    office_phone_number = PhoneNumberField(_('main office phone number'),
        blank=True, null=True)
    toll_free_number = PhoneNumberField(_('toll free number'),
        blank=True, null=True)
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(_('mobile phone number'),
        blank=True, null=True)
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(_('main office fax'),
        blank=True, null=True)
    card_mailing_address = models.CharField(max_length=10,
        choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    card_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=3,
        choices=CARD_QUANTITY_CHOICES)


class RushOrder(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='rushorders')
    rush_order = models.BooleanField()
    in_hand_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)


class OrderNote(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='ordernotes')
    add_note = models.BooleanField()
    notes = models.TextField()
```

So again what I'm trying to do is get these formsets to save to the database, that way the admin will have the stationary order saved for printing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're here to learn, and your code is quite complex (I'd need **all** the code necessary to reproduce your problem, which includes models), I'm not going to answer with a code fix.

Instead, you will learn how to use a debugger, which will fix "I still don't know where I am going wrong".

1. **Install ipdb**, because it's more convenient than just pdb, `pip install ipdb`.
2. **Set a breakpoint**, in your view, add this line `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`.
3. **Run the code in the devserver**, the devserve should pause at the breakpoint, and show the code it's paused at.
4. **Get to know ipdb**, type "h", it will show a list of command, try to overread the documentation of each command, you can also check [this article](http://www.gregaker.net/2012/apr/05/debugging-python-with-pdb-or-ipdb/) which includes a video.
5. **Step through your code**, by typing "n" in the debugger, the interpreter should move to the next line of code, "d" to step in, "u" to step out, etc ... You can execute Python from the prompt at any time.

You will know what Python is doing exactly, fixing "I still don't know where I am going wrong". Also, you'll become an invincible programmer (or something like that hahaha)

Comment: thank you so much! I'm going to set this up now! In the meantime I'll add the models as well, I'm not looking for the answer though :) thank you again!

Comment: I got the ipdb set up and working which lead me to find that my foreignkey for contact is null which is not allowing this to save. So on to that now :)